# WordPress Export/Import Posts+Image

Tags: wordpress, import, export

I am trying to migrate the posts from the previous site to the new site. After using Tools -> Export -> Posts. The posts on the site are importing fine, however, the attached images on the posts are still linked to the previous address.

Answer (score 0):

Change permalink "day and name" to plain and save it after that reverse follow this step.